# Regex matching phone numbers (with PHP preg_replace) Part 2

Tags: php, regex

So ive been using preg_replace in PHP to match and replace phone numbers. My goal is quite simple: i want to match all character sequences which contain spaces, numbers, dashes and + sign with a minimum length of 6, so a character sequence of +12 0 123 44 44 555 would match.

String length of the $subject can be up to 1000 characters, if that makes a difference.

i came up with this regex:

preg_replace('/[0-9 +-]{6,}/', ' [hidden] ', '+12 0 123 44 44 555', -1, $count);
my expectation is i get a string of

[hidden]
what i get is

[hidden]  44 555
Im sure its obvious but i cant seem to figure out why the whole sequence doesent match.

I tested it on https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html and also tried some suggested Regexes like:
[0-9\h+-]{6,}
or
preg_replace('/+?\d(?:[\s+()-]*\d){5,}/', ' [hidden] ', '+12 0 123 44 44 555');

but both still only replace part of the phone number.

(previous post where only part of the question was answered and the post was closed: [Regex matching phone numbers (with PHP preg_replace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71690530/regex-matching-phone-numbers-with-php-preg-replace) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your string contains non-ASCII whitespace characters, you need to use

```php
preg_replace('/[0-9\s+-]{6,}/u', ' [hidden] ', '+12 0 123 44 44 555', -1, $count);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/meLKJ).

The regular space is replaced with a `\s` shorthand character class, and the `u` flag is used to ensure the string is handled as a Unicode string and not a byte string by the regex engine, and `\s` now matches any Unicode whitespace chars.

Comment: That did it thanks!